# Java client starting up when IBM MQ server is down or unreachable

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I realize there is a method to set on MQConnectionFactory to attempt to reconnect if the connection of a consumer or producer is broken. However, I'm wondering if one can do something similar for an application that is starting up and setting up consumers and producers. The code I have right now will not recover if the server is down when my client application comes up.

Is there a common/recommended practice here?

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would simply be to use the tools that are provided in the Java language itself. For example, you could write a loop with exception handling to retry the initial connection or JNDI lookup a configurable number of times. It's hard to provide more specific recommendations when you haven't provided any client code of your own.

Comment: FYI, I ended up opting for using external mechanism to detect a bad state and restart if needed. In this case, Kubernetes' facilities for liveness/readiness.

Comment: How are you using that from your application?

Comment: It's a Spring Boot application, so I extend AbstractHealthIndicator, and implement a doHealthCheck method.